# Jenkins launches 2 builds when manually triggered

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've noticed a recent issue in both our instances of Jenkins. When launching a job manually, it launches twice. I've no idea what is causing it, but it's happening across multiple jobs. I used to think it was a display issue because cancelling one of the jobs would cancel the other. But, once I check the rule for not building concurrently, I see the second job queued up and have it fire afterwards and if the job is something like update a local folder from git, the second build will fail (since the first one already updated) which shows me that they are not the same build but instead are two different ones firing up at the same time. For all intent and purposes, it's a trivial issue, but not knowing what's causing it is driving me insane.

Anyone ran into anything like this before?

Comment: Please provide details about the build trigger - do you Poll SCM? If you wait the jobs to finish, will the log contain same operations executed? Does this happen when you configure cron schedule and jobs are triggered automatically?

Comment: So, it only happens when I go in and launch the build manually. Cron jobs seem to be exempt. I don't poll scm, have periodic build times. It affects all my jobs though when launched manually. Looking in the workspace, if my job is called test, I have two folders, test and test@2 and they both execute operations on their own and often overlap

Comment: Also happens when I go in a build and replay it. It ends up being duplicated there too

Comment: #1 Does your job have parameters? #2 Create another job (hello world) and build it manually to validate if it is an error in the whole instance or just is your custom job #3 Share us  the jenkins version, your server os (I hope it's not windows), and a minimal sample of your job: free style, pipeline, etc

Comment: Yes I do have parameters and trying out an hello world job, the issue doesn't happen if the project has no parameters but happens when I add one. I created a new job and had it just have a batch task to echo hello world. Works fine. Tried again and had it echo a parameter, same double run of job happens. Tried a few times to confirm.

I am running 2.303.1 on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Update: At one point, updating to a newer version of Jenkins fixed this issue. I am still not sure what exactly was happening, but for future reference, the issue was that any build with parameters would double trigger.